# Can anyone please help me how can I start with blockchain testing,Deploy application and testing app

Tags: blockchain, testing

I am completely new to blockchain testing.Can someone please help me with how can I start with blockchain testing and procedure from where I should start and material for the same if possible.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for this forum. If you already know how to write smart contracts, you could google "testing smart contracts" and take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Ethereum Blockchain. Following resources would be helpful when you just getting started.

(1) Learn about Solidity: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

(2) Some YouTube resources:
=> Deploy smart contract: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbDbDK88-fc
=> Verify smart contract: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3cpYgUS1sc

(3) Truffle framework for testing, deploying and debugging smart contract:
https://truffleframework.com/tutorials

As newbie, please keep things as simple as possible to avoid overwhelm and you will be master when you keep going.. Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou Yogesh, .Will go through these links.